# Easy way to see who likes a certain link?

Tags: facebook

Is there an easy way to provide a link to facebook to see how many and, if possible, who likes a certain link? Preferably without actually having to write code? Maybe a rest call?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://stackoverflow.com
```

number of shares

Comment: what if you are the admin for a domain, can you see who is liking the page? i know that if you have a facebook page you can see who it is...

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook APIs does not give you the user ID of users who have liked a URL, obviously for privacy reasons.

Comment: The total count of 'likes' is available though.